# How to get my JQuery to act on my button rather than the input element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the following button element to increment the input number by one while the user holds down the left mouse key pressing the button.  With the code below, it is almost doing said behaviour, except for it only does that when I click on the arrows built into the html input element.  I want that to happen when I click on my button element and I don't see why that is not happening.

HTML

```
<input type="number" class = "margin" value="0">
<button id="clicker" type="button" class ="away">Add one</button>
```

JQuery--

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function decrement(field) {
        field.val(parseInt(field.val(), 10) - 1);
    }
    var timeout, clicker = $('#clicker');

    $("#clicker").mousedown(function () {
        timeout = setInterval(function () {
            // Do something continuously 
            decrement($(this).siblings('.margin'));
        }, 500);

        return false;
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function () {
        clearInterval(timeout);
        return false;
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<html>
<input type="number" class = "margin" value="0">
<button id="clicker" type="button" class ="away">Add one</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `click()` in stead of `mousedown()` and `mouseup()`, also you are not getting `$(this)` in `setInterval()` try this,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function decrement(field) {
        field.val(parseInt(field.val(), 10) - 1);
    }
    var timeout, clicker = $('#clicker');
    $("#clicker").click(function (e) {// use click in place of mousedown
       $that=$(this);// take a copy of ($this);
       timeout = setInterval(function () {
            // Do something continuously 
            decrement($that.siblings('.margin'));// use $that in place of $(this)
       }, 1000);
       return false;
    });
    $(document).click(function (e) {// use click in place of mouseup
        clearInterval(timeout);
        return false;
    });
});
```

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4sx9C/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your context of `this`. You need to create a handle to the button within the mousedown event, before you define the interval:

```
var timeout;

$("#theButton").on('mousedown', function () {
    var theButton = 'this'; // handle on the button
    timeout = setInterval(function () {
        var value = +$(theButton).prevAll("#field").val();
        value++;
        $(theButton).prevAll("#field").val(value);
    }, 500);
});

$("#theButton").on('mouseup', function () {
    clearInterval(timeout);
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kw963/1/)